# How do I pass a bean to a JSP tag as a parameter?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, jsp-tags

I've created a custom JSP tag that is supposed to accept a list of products to render, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the list to the tag. The product list exists as a page-scoped bean. The web app is written in Struts 1.2.x using the [Struts taglib](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/userGuide/struts-bean.html).

Here's a simplified version of my code:

#### renderProducts.tag

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" body-content="empty" %>
<%@ attribute name="products" required="false" type="ProductIf[]" %>
<logic:iterate id="product" name="${products}" type="ProductIf">
    <!-- Render the product -->
</logic:iterate>
```

#### ProductDetail.jsp

```
<bean:define id="relatedProducts" name="productMgr" property="relatedProducts />
<my:renderProducts products="${relatedProducts}" />
```

However, when I view the page, I get an exception:

> Unable to convert string "${relatedProducts}" to class "[Lcom.foo.ProductIf;" for attribute "products": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

So it seems the `${}` syntax is not what I need to be doing, since it is being interpreted as a literal string anyway. I've also tried passing in the name of the bean without the `${}` with the same result. What is the proper syntax?

(Note: Please forgive me if this question is built on a shaky foundation of bad assumptions, but I'm new to Java EE development and there's a fair amount of fumbling-in-the-dark going on.)

Comment: Have you disabled the EL in your JSP with isELIgnored, or globally in the web.xml? What's the DTD of your web.xml?

Comment: @JBNizet No, EL hasn't been explicitly disabled anywhere that I can think to check. The DTD of web.xml is `<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html:

> To deactivate the evaluation of EL expressions, you specify the
>   isELIgnored attribute of the page directive:
>
> ```
> <%@ page isELIgnored ="true|false" %>
> ```
>
> The valid values of this attribute are true and false. If it is true,
>   EL expressions are ignored when they appear in static text or tag
>   attributes. If it is false, EL expressions are evaluated by the
>   container.
>
> The default value varies depending on the version of the web
>   application deployment descriptor. **The default mode for JSP pages
>   delivered using a Servlet 2.3 or earlier descriptor is to ignore EL
>   expressions; this provides backward compatibility**. The default mode
>   for JSP pages delivered with a Servlet 2.4 descriptor is to evaluate
>   EL expressions; this automatically provides the default that most
>   applications want.

(emphasis mine)

So, either switch to a servlet 2.4 or higner descriptor, if your container supports it, or activate EL using `<%@ page isELIgnored = "false" %>`.

Comment: That did the trick. Now I have to deal with the fact that Struts Taglib 1.2.x doesn't support EL expressions, but that's a problem for another day...